# Dealing with Iterable in apache-spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Lets say I have a RDD[Int]. After I do a groupBy by some discriminator function I am left with an RDD[(Int, Iterable[Int])].

Since this Iterable can be large it should be distributed among nodes. But there are no means to deal with it like with an RDD.

For example if I want to further do some pairing and aggregating by key with one of the Iterables.

Or lets say I want to sort one of them and find the [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median)

I suppose it is not legal to call one of the .toList or .toSeq methods here because the regular scala collections are not distributed.

So what is the right approach for dealing with Iterables?

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly don't want to do a `groupBy`. One of the biggest performance issues in Spark jobs is the shuffling of data around the cluster because of poor partitioning and data locality. If you're doing a `groupBy`, presumably you want to partition your data on that key and keep your data as close to each other as possible. So in the end, a `groupBy` suggests you actually *don't* want your data distributed away from the partition if you can avoid it.

But you *want* things need to be more distributed. You probably want to do something like this:

```
val rdd: RDD[Int] = ...
val rdd2: RDD[(Int, Int)] = rdd.map(i => (key(i), i))
val rdd3: RDD[(Int, Int)] = rdd2.reduceByKey((accumulator, i) => myFunction(accumulator, i))
```

Comment: You are right, groupBy has issues, but there are other ways of getting an Iterable. For example groupByKey. My question was how to deal with Iterables, not how to avoid them. One of my use cases is finding the median of an Iterable[Int].

Comment: No, it isn't that `groupBy` "has issues." You just fundamentally misunderstand the Spark API. Also, your `Iterable` "use case" exists only as a function of your obsession with `groupBy`. Since you are so certain the problem is with the Spark API and not your thought process, have you at least verified that operating on `Iterable`s is a problem? If Spark can do some machine learning with Gradient-Boosted Trees and latent Dirichlet allocation, I'm pretty sure it can calculate a median.

Answer (score 0):

you can use aggregateByKey or reduceByKey [transformations](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#more-on-rdd-operations) and in order to take the result you can use [actions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#actions) like collect